# DataCloneError: The object could not be cloned. [Firefox Browser]

Tags: reactjs, object, react-hooks

I'm getting DataClone error when trying to transfer Data as an object into another page

On **Crome** browser I'm getting the error given below:

> DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': function () { [native code] } could not be cloned.

**app.js**

```
const app = () => {
  const profile = useContext(ProfileContext);
  console.log(typeof profile) // object type
  
  const gotoEditPage = () => {
   history.push({
     pathname: '/setting',
     state: {profile}
   })
  }
 return (
  <>
   <button onClick={gotoEditPage}>Next</button>
  </>
 )
}
```

Whether it is a Browser specific error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

DataCloneError actually occured because I was trying to transfer **methods** in an object. So to avoid this error just parse Object into JSON as given below

```
const parseData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(profile));
```

Now **parseData** can easily be transfered to another page.